# customize UIBarButtonItem in Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, ios5, ios4

I was trying to customizing the UIBarButtonItem in Navigation Bar
I found that there is a property in UIBarButtonItem : "tintColor" , and I set it like this

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

It works well, but if I try this :

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName"]];
```

*1*. It doesn't work as expect , however , the leftBarButtonItem shows a **black** appearance ,why ?

If I try a **clearColor** :

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.tintColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

*2*. The leftBarButtonItem shows a **black** appearance still, why ?

*3*. I want to customize it with a pattern image like above , how can I do that ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check this sample code for customizing navigation bar and back button
https://github.com/boctor/idev-recipes/tree/master/CustomBackButton